# mongo: collection not found ReferenceError: auditoria is not defined

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this message on a very simple `find` command:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> use MPI
switched to db MPI
rs0:PRIMARY> show collections;
hes-auditoria-mpi-fhir
hes-auditoria-schemas
rs0:PRIMARY> db.hes-auditoria-mpi-fhir.find();
2021-05-20T14:20:05.502+0200 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: auditoria is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try  `db['hes-auditoria-mpi-fhir'].find();`

Comment: You may want to use an _underscore_ (`_`) instead of the _hyphen_ (`-`) as part of the name of collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) helper:

```
db.getCollection("hes-auditoria-mpi-fhir").find()
```

It's been added exactly for this purpose. From the docs:

> **db.getCollection(name)**
>
> Returns a collection or a view object that is functionally equivalent to using the `db.<collectionName>` syntax. The method is useful for a collection or a view whose name might interact with the mongo shell itself, such as names that begin with _ or that match a database shell method.